# OKHttp3 max-stale cache

Tags: retrofit, cache-control, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm starting out with caching and Retrofit/OKHttp3 in Android. We need to support offline mode/server down for our app and I'm trying to figure out how to configure the cache correctly to support that. The idea is to get a fresh copy from the server when it's available (or a 304 if nothing changed). If the server are down or if app is offline we need to fetch the cached response.

I configured the Cache-control like this:

```
Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=0, max-stale=50, private
```

This works pretty good but what I don't understand is why OKHttp serves the cached response even when the "max-stale" has passed? I thought that after 50 seconds I would get a 504 - Unsatisfiable request because the max-stale period has passed?

This is the interceptor I use for OKHttp:

```
.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        try {
                            if (!NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable(model.getApplicationContext())) {
                                return getCachedResponse(chain);
                            }
                            Request request = chain.request();
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        } catch (Exception exception) {
                            return getCachedResponse(chain);
                        }
                    }
                })

    private static Response getCachedResponse(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE)
            .removeHeader("Pragma")
            .build();

    Response forceCacheResponse = chain.proceed(request);
    return forceCacheResponse.newBuilder()
            .build();
}
```

Any ideas how to configure the cache so that it won't serve the cached response after the max-stale period has passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, after you ask a question you find the answer. I understand that the cache continues to serve content even after the max-stale period has passed because I used the CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE. That adds an "only-if-cache" flag and ALSO sets the max-stale to a very high value which overrides the max-stale value the server passed in the first place. I solved it by creating another cachecontrol with a max-stale value I define:

```
    private static Response getCachedResponse(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

    CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl
            .Builder()
            .onlyIfCached()
            .maxStale(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .cacheControl(cacheControl)
            .removeHeader("Pragma")
            .build();

    Response forceCacheResponse = chain.proceed(request);
    return forceCacheResponse.newBuilder()
            .build();
}
```